# Unexpected character on the end of array returned from controller to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am having a weird problem in my codeigniter view. In my webapp using codeigniter I'm sending an array of rows returned from codeigniter model to controller and from there to the view. My problem is that, when I print the array in view I get a `1` at the end of the array. It looks like as shown:

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 12 [item_code] => code1 [item_name] => part [brand] => qwerty [quantity] => 3 [retail_price] => 123 [cost] => 145 [alert_quantity] => 10) ) 1`

Even when I didn't return the row from model, Still I get this `1`, when I take the count of array. I didn't understand whats wrong. I'm stuck here for last 2 days.

Here is my code:

Model: product_model.php

```
public function alertproducts()
{
$myQuery = "select * FROM tab_products";
$q = $this->db->query($myQuery);
if( $q->num_rows() > 0 )
{
foreach (($q->result()) as $row)
{
$qty=$row->quantity;
$alertqty=$row->alert_quantity;
if($qty<=$alertqty)
{
$id[]=$row;
}
}
if(!empty($id))
{
return $id;
}
}
return FALSE;
}
```

Controller:product.php

```
public function alertproduct()
{
$data['alertproduct']= $this->product_model->alertproducts();
$this->load->view('commons/header');
$this->load->view('productalerts',$data);
$this->load->view('commons/footer');
}
```

Can anybody help me with this to find where am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to do some debug.The provided code is not enough to produce your problem.Tips:comment your all codes and uncomment one by one and find where is the problem and why.

Answer (score 0):

That 1 at the end means that you most likely echoed your `print_r`. Try using `var_dump` instead.. also change your SQL query to this: `SELECT * FROM tab_products WHERE quantity <= alert_quantity` or even better use Codeigniter's active record/query builder, its way cleaner like so:

```
public function alertproducts() {
    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from("tab_products");
    $this->db->where("quantity <= alert_quantity");
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $q->result_array();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```